# Shellcode not running if declared as vector of unsigned chars

Tags: c++, shellcode

Why isn't the shellcode running in this example

example 1

```
    std::vector<unsigned char> decrypted(encrypted.size());
    void *exec = VirtualAlloc(0, decrypted.size(), MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);
    memcpy(exec, &decrypted.front(), decrypted.size());
    ((void(*)())exec)();
```

when I type `cout << &decrypted.front()` I get the payload in the console and adding `> out.txt` I save the payload to a text files then view it in notepad copy it and then use it with

example 2

```
    unsigned char out[] = "\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01"
    void *exec = VirtualAlloc(0, sizeof(out), MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);
    memcpy(exec, out, sizeof(out));
    ((void(*)())exec)();
```

Isn't a vector a dynamic array
If I can output the shellcode to the screen with `*decrypted.front()` then I should be able to pass it to `memcpy`

The same payload taken from example 1 runs fine in example 2

Comment: Have you accounted for the null byte at the end of the out array?

Comment: The question is off-topic on Security SE.

Answer (score 0):

`memcpy` takes two pointers, the destination and the source.  In example 1, the source is the address of a temporary iterator, not the start of the array underlying the vector, so what you're copying isn't the data in the vector, but the bytes of the iterator.

If you want to use `memcpy`, you'll need to copy data using two arrays or pointers to buffers, or you can use iterators to copy from one place to the other, but not both.